# Delete text in file using bash script in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create an script that deletes few lines from a file containing the following text

```
you.com
me.ac.id
burger.co.us
manheal.com
```

If i want to delete this:

```
burger.co.us
```

How is the syntax in shell programming??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sed "/burger.co.us/d" < inputfile > outputfile
```

will match and delete that line from `inputfile` and write to `outputfile` using [redirection](http://www.dsj.net/compedge/shellbasics1.html).

Note that you can't read your input and write to the same file using the above. Instead use the `-i` field to specify replacement *in-place*.

See [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for more about sed.

Comment: Or `sed -i -e "/burger.co.us/d" singlefile` to replace in-place.

Comment: Yes, I think you should add it to your answer before someone tries to do `sed ... < file > file` :).